# Sports Seeding Function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a sports seeding program in Python. I have the start of it below. When I run the program my state placer doesn't print out on the top. Can anyone give me a clue as to why it wouldn't sort towards the top?

```
seeded_players = {
2: {'name': 'George', "highschool": "AHS",   "win_rate": 0,  "state": "", "regionals": 6 },
3: {'name': 'George', "highschool": "SCHS",   "win_rate": 0,  "state": "", "regionals": "" },
1: {'name': 'Bob', "highschool": "SHS",   "win_rate": 0.4,  "state": 1, "regionals": 4 },
}

def state_sorting(request):
    # Always sort first in states at the top of list.

    for x in seeded_players:
        if x["State"] == 1:
            x.sort(-1)
    else:
        None

print(seeded_players)
```

> > python3 seeding.py
> > `{2: {'name': 'George', 'highschool': 'AHS', 'win_rate': 0, 'state': '', 'regionals': 6},  3: {'name': 'George', 'highschool': 'SCHS', 'win_rate': 0, 'state': '', 'regionals': ''},  1: {'name': 'Bob', 'highschool': 'SHS', 'win_rate': 0.4, 'state': 1, 'regionals': 4}}`

Comment: `id.sort(-2)` -- what do you think that is going to do?  And do remember that `"State"` and `"state"` are not equal.  And do you realize you never use your `Sixteen_Man_seeding` class anywhere in this program?

Comment: Thank you, I simplified what I am trying to do here. The -1  or -2 is to always add the person at the beginning of the list or the second spot.

Comment: This code is still nonsense.  `for x in seeded_players:` gives you the keys one by one.  `x` will be 2, 3, 1.  It will not have the values.  You still do `x["State"]` when the key is actually `"state"`.  And still, `x.sort(-1)` doesn't do anything useful.  And again, you have a function (`state_sorting`), but you never call it.  Most important, YOU SHOULDN'T SORT A DICTIONARY.   Do you want this to be a list, kept in your specific sorted order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this reflects what you were trying to do.  Among the changes:

- I've made your `seeded_players` into a list, not a dict.  That's the proper way to store things that need to be sorted.
- I've changed your `state_sorting` into a sort key function.  Given a row, it returns a "key" that tells how the row should be sorted.  In this case, the "state" value is most important, followed by the "regionals", followed by the "win_rate".
- I'm now USING this function, which you were not, by sorting the list using my function as the key.

```py
from pprint import pprint
seeded_players = [
    {'id': 2, 'name': 'George', "highschool": "AHS",   "win_rate": 0,  "state": 0, "regionals": 6 },
    {'id': 3, 'name': 'George', "highschool": "SCHS",   "win_rate": 0,  "state": 0, "regionals": 0 },
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'Bob', "highschool": "SHS",   "win_rate": 0.4,  "state": 1, "regionals": 4 },
]

def state_sorting(row):
    return row['state'],row['regionals'],row['win_rate']

seeded_players.sort( key=state_sorting, reverse=True )
pprint(seeded_players)
```

Output:

```
[{'highschool': 'SHS',
  'id': 1,
  'name': 'Bob',
  'regionals': 4,
  'state': 1,
  'win_rate': 0.4},
 {'highschool': 'AHS',
  'id': 2,
  'name': 'George',
  'regionals': 6,
  'state': 0,
  'win_rate': 0},
 {'highschool': 'SCHS',
  'id': 3,
  'name': 'George',
  'regionals': 0,
  'state': 0,
  'win_rate': 0}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show us a
unit test
that exercises this code.

I can't imagine how you'd call this without
it raising an exception:

```
    self.id = id
    ...
    if id["State"] == 1:
        id.sort(-1)
```

given:

```
>>> id
<built-in function id>
```

---

You want something like this:

```
from pprint import pp
from collections import namedtuple

Player = namedtuple("Player", "state regionals win_rate name highschool")

seeded_players = [
    Player(1, 4, .4, "Bob", "SHS"),
    Player(0, 6, 0,  "George", "AHS"),
    Player(0, 0, 0,  "George", "SCHS"),
]
```

Then it's as simple as

```
>>> pp(sorted(seeded_players))
[Player(state=0, regionals=0, win_rate=0, name='George', highschool='SCHS'),
 Player(state=0, regionals=6, win_rate=0, name='George', highschool='AHS'),
 Player(state=1, regionals=4, win_rate=0.4, name='Bob', highschool='SHS')]
```

Comment: Thank you, I simplified my example. I am not trying to sort, I am trying to place people in certain spots in a dictionary permanently. I like the 'pp' and 'named tuple' modules, thanks.

Comment: What's the difference between "sorting" and "placing people in certain spots"?  That's exactly what sorting is.